# Unwanted strings using typedef in constructor

Tags: xml, xquery, xml-namespaces, saxon

I am using Saxon HE 9.6 to translate some XML to Yin elements using XQuery.

When I generate Yin grouping and `typedef` elements using XQuery constructors, I am getting unwanted `xmlns=""` strings in the output.

For example, when I use a constructor containing:

```
typedef name="some_name"
```

the output that is generated looks like

```
typedef xmlns="" name="some_name"
```

Note that the elements are enclosed in less than/greater than characters in both the constructor and the output.

Why is the `xmlns=""` being generated and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Hello! I edited your question to make it more readable, for instance identing the code. Edited the title so it's more easily found, and added a tag to make it more visible.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the xmlns="" ? Every XML element and attribute is always in a namespace.  What you see is the global namespace.

If you are seeing this inside of another element of another namespace, then it is likely that when you created the new element, you did not define a specific namespace matching the parent element's namespace. In this case, you see the specific global namespace for each of those elements.

Example

```
<foo xmlns="http://www.example.com/foo">
    <bar>baz</bar>
</foo>
```

If I add in programatically the element `<bar2>baz2</bar2>`, I may end up with:

```
<foo xmlns="http://www.example.com/foo">
    <bar>baz</bar>
    <bar2 xmlns="">ba2</bar2>
</foo>
```

Comment: The problem is that the xmlns strings are being added by XQuery not by my constructor itself and are also not consistent.  Not every element has then and not even every typedef or grouping element.  The real problem is that I am then post-processing the XQuery output with a tool called "pyang" which generates Yang  object models from the Yin constructs I created with XQuery, and pyang generates errors due to the extra xmlns strings.  I need to know why they are being automatically generated (but not always) and if there is a way to stop XQuery from doing it.